# Can't access FormData using sign-up form from Material-UI example templates

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to react and fiddling around with Material-UI. I'm trying to use `DataPicker` and then access the form data with the `new FormData()` - even though it seems to use `TextField`, values for `start` and `end` are not present. I've used this [SignUp](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/sign-up) form for the beginning.

How do I get them?

**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import EventAvailableIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EventAvailable';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

import MyDataPicker from './MyDataPicker';
    
const theme = createTheme();

export default function SignUp() {
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(data);
        // Display the key/value pairs
        for (var pair of data.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]);
        }
    };

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
                <CssBaseline />
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        marginTop: 8,
                        display: 'flex',
                        flexDirection: 'column',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                >
                    <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'primary.main' }}>
                        <EventAvailableIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                        Make Calendar link
                    </Typography>
                    <Box component="form" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
                        <Grid container spacing={2}>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <MyDataPicker
                                    name="start"
                                    label="Start date"
                                    date={null}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <MyDataPicker
                                    name="end"
                                    label="End date"
                                    date={null}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    name="timezone"
                                    label="Timezone"
                                    defaultValue="Europe/Prague"
                                    helperText="See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php"
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    name="title"
                                    label="Title"
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    multiline
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    name="description"
                                    label="Description"
                                    rows={4}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    fullWidth
                                    name="location"
                                    label="Location"
                                />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            fullWidth
                            variant="contained"
                            sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                        >
                            Generate links
                        </Button>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

**MyDataPicker.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
//https://mui.com/api/date-time-picker/
import DateTimePicker from '@mui/lab/DateTimePicker';


export default function MaterialUIPickers(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(props.date);

    console.log(props);

    const handleChange = (newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
        console.log(props);
    };

    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <Stack spacing={3}>
                <DateTimePicker
                    label={props.label}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
                    clearable
                    cleartext="Clear"
                />
            </Stack>
        </LocalizationProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `event.currentTarget` is an `HTMLFormElement`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah, I'm pretty sure. The other form elements (`timezone`,`location`,`title` and `description` are parsed correctly).

Comment: I would do `console.log(event.currentTarget.nodeName)` to make sure.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's `FORM` so it looks good. But it seems like the attribute `name ` is not rendered on the Datapicker - even if it's passed in props.name. If I add it manually, it starts working.
`<DateTimePicker renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />} ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 params with the same name `props` inside `MaterialUIPickers`:

```
export default function MaterialUIPickers(props /* ---------------> props 1 */) {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <Stack spacing={3}>
        <DateTimePicker
          {...}
          renderInput={(props  /* ---------------> props 2 */) => {
            return (
              <TextField {...props} />
            );
          }}
          clearable
          cleartext="Clear"
        />
      </Stack>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Because props 1 is from the outer scope, it will be overridden by props 2, which prevents you from passing the `name` attribute down to the `input` element, that's why the `form` can't find the field value. The fix is pretty simple, rename one of the props to differentiate between the 2 of them:

```
renderInput={(params) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      {...props} // put props after to let it overrides the name here
      inputProps={{
        ...params.inputProps,
        ...props.inputProps
      }}
      InputProps={{
        ...params.InputProps,
        ...props.InputProps
      }}
    />
  );
}}
```